# Footer not sticking to the bottom of the page in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a website using react but **I can't get the footer to stick to the bottom**, when there isn't enough content the footer is showing up right after the content of the page not at the bottom.I tried almost everything, I think there is a problem with the structure it self like from the beginning

Here is my code:

App.css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

body{
    min-height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
footer.footer{
    margin-top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Footer.js:

```
import React from "react";
import './Footer.css';
import {GrGithub, GrInstagram, GrLinkedin, GrTwitter} from 'react-icons/gr';

export const Footer = () =>{
    return (
        <footer className="footer">
            <p>2022 &copy; All right Reserved <br/> Khaled Nadam</p>
            <ul className="footer-social">
                        <li><GrInstagram /></li>
                        <li><GrLinkedin /></li>
                        <li><GrGithub /></li>
                        <li><GrTwitter /></li>                
                    </ul>
        </footer>
    );
}
```

Footer.css:

```
.footer{
    background-color: #1C4B82;
    color: #DAE1E7;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer p{
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: .8rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer .footer-social{
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
.footer .footer-social li{
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are not using `position property` in your `CSS`.

Try below code:

```
body {
  position: relative;
} 

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: now it is going over the content

Answer (score -1):

you need to add position: absolute to footer css.

```
.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    }
```

Comment: it is on the bottom of the browser page now so when I scroll down it is becoming at middle of the page.